# Execute code when form is closed in VBA (Excel 2007)

Tags: forms, vba, excel

I would like to execute some code when a user closes a form using the x button in the top right corner of the window (I have the form load when the excel spreadsheet is opened, and it hides Excel. I want to exit excel once the form is closed, or at least show excel again so the user may exit it manually)

Looking at the form properties, the Unload property is not present, nor am I able to figure out how to make a function which executes when the form is closed.

Unfortunately, coding this in VB is not an option, it must be VBA.

I'm aware of the code needed to unhide Excel or quit it outright, just not how to tie it to the unload event.

Answer (score 23):

You can use **QueryClose** event of the UserForm as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        ' Your codes
        ' Tip: If you want to prevent closing UserForm by Close (×) button in the right-top corner of the UserForm, just uncomment the following line:
        ' Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also use vbFormControlMenu like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        'Your code goes here
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 19):

A colleague was able to provide the answer, including example here for everybody else

```
Private Sub userform_terminate()

    'Code goes here

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this is also fired when hiding a form. Use MRS1367's answer if you only want to capture the close button (x) in the right top corner!

Comment: The event `Terminate` is also triggered if any custom action does a `Unload me` to close the form, so using the event **`QueryClose`** is better suited to only check if the x button has been pressed, as said OfficialBAMM. See the answer given by MRS1367.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Unload Me` in VBA to close a form.  Just put the code to close Excel immediately following that.

Comment: Thanks, but how does this allow me to execute code when the user clicks the x button? Perhaps I didn't make the question clear, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Oh I see, I (incorrectly) assumed the user was exiting via a form button click, not the x button on the window.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim msgRes As VbMsgBoxResult
    msgRes = MsgBox("Exit form ?", vbYesNo)
    If msgRes = vbYes Then
        'optional code
    ElseIf msgRes = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear how this provides an answer to the question. Please expound upon this answer to point to the original problem and your particular solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to prevent the form from closing when the X button was click using the following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
   Cancel = MsgBox("Please confirm cancellation", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion) = vbCancel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:-

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender as Object, e as FormClosingEventArgs) _ 
    Handles Form1.FormClosing

    //Code you want to execute

End Sub
```

Comment: There should be a FormClosing event that you can select for your Form, when you are looking at the source code. Here is a link to a example: 

http://img385.imageshack.us/img385/3966/wat3am9.jpg

Comment: There is no FormClosing event in UserForm (Excel VBA).