# Add Action in X at userform macro VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform in macro which gets the source from another workbook(test.xlsm). So I used this code below to open that workbook without showing it.

```
Const fromFile = "C:\Users\excel\test.xlsm"
Dim srcBook As Workbook
Set srcBook =   
Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\excel\test.xlsm", _
UpdateLinks:=False, _
ReadOnly:=True, _
AddToMRU:=False)
```

[image: Userform]

So when the macro run, the userform shown up and also the test.xlsm in background. However, there are some users who close the userform using "X" symbol at the right top corner. and sometimes, there is an error because the source (text.xlsm) didn't close properly.

I am wondering if there is a way to add an action if the user click the "X" button in my userform? So I want to close the test.xlsm which run in background if the users click "X" button.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34556520/7690982) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3511903/7690982) and close the workbook properly when the userform is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `QueryClose`-Event of the form. If you set `Cancel` to `true`, the form will **not** close

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Workbooks("test.xlsm").close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need in the UserForm, to be able to act when it is requested to close:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Debug.Print "You Exited"
End Sub
```

Once the user clicks on the `X` you would see the "You Exited" printed on the immediate window.